# Question regarding inference in solution to indefinite integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I'm an adult learner, slowly working my way through *James Stewart's Calculus 8th Edition - Single Variable Calculus Early Transcendentals*.

I am currently working through some exercises on indefinite integrals, specifically problems pertaining to the Substitution Rule (Section 5.5), and am at a loss to understand the justification for a particular inference provided in the solutions manual I have available to me.

**The Problem**

Find the indefinite integral of the following:

$$ \int{\frac{\sin{2x}}{1 + \cos^2 x}}\ dx $$

which is transformed using the double angle formula to:

$$ 2 \int{\frac{\sin x \cos x}{1 + \cos^2 x}}\ dx $$

**The Approach**

Letting $u = \cos x $,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} &= -\sin x\ \\
du &= -\sin x\ dx \\
\frac{du}{- \sin x} &= dx
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the original problem may be restated using the Substitution Rule as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
2 \int{\frac{\sin x\ u}{1+u^2}\ \frac{-du}{\sin x}} & = -2 \int{\frac{u}{1+u^2}}\ du \\
\end{align}
$$

**The Troublesome Inference**

At this juncture, I am at a loss of what to do. To date, this stage of these exercises required inverting some one of the rules of differentiation, but I feel blind as to which I am meant to use here.

The solutions manual provides the following inference:

$$
\begin{align}
2 \int{\frac{\sin x\ u}{1+u^2}\ \frac{-du}{\sin x}} & = -2 \int{\frac{u}{1+u^2}}\ du \\
& = -2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \ln{1 + u^2} + C
\end{align}
$$

**The Question**

While I do understand that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln{x} = \frac{1}{x}$, wouldn't an antiderivative of $\frac{-1}{1 + u^2}$ be some composite function requiring the Chain Rule to differentiate?

I'm struggling to understand the inference based on the tools I currently have available to me.

Hopefully this is clear enough that someone can provide some guidance.

Thank you,

Pierre

Comment: Let $v = 1+u^2$.  Can you finish this substitution from here?

Comment: Oh!, You just perform an additional substitution?

Comment: Yes.  Notice that the numerator is (up to an easily fixed constant multiple) the derivative of the denominator.

Comment: How wonderfully clever. Thank you so much, Eric. :)

Comment: So I suppose then that one could, if necessary (though I'm not savvy enough to think up an example), use the substitution method recursively as often as is necessary?

Comment: Of course.  Several integration techniques replace one integral with a new one, so we are moving through "the space of integrals" hoping to land on one we know how to integrate.

Comment: @EricTowers - "Space of integrals" - I like that thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the indefinite integral of the following:

$$ \int{\frac{\sin{2x}}{1 + \cos^2 x}}\ dx $$

Step 1 :

$$ 2 \int{\frac{\sin x\space{cos  ~x}}{1 + \cos^2 x}}\ dx $$

Step 2 : use-base substitution

Let $u = cos~x~,$

$$ \frac{du}{dx}=-~sin~x     $$

$$ =-2 \int{\frac{u}{1 + u^2 }}\ du $$

Step 3 : again base substitution

Let $v = 1 + u^2 ~, $

$$\frac{du}{dx}= 1 + 2~u$$

$$= -\int{\frac{1}{v }}\ dv $$

$$= -~ln|v|+c $$

Final step :

$$ =-~ln|~{1 + \cos^2 x}| + c $$